# ng-repeat does not update when adding to an associative array using bracket notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to Angular and I am trying to add/push an item into an associative array. However, when I use bracket notation, the data in ng-repeat does not update. I have no idea why.

In JS/coffee Controller file I have this:

```
$scope.openDoc = (contentNumber)->
    $scope.openDocs[contentNumber] = {"content":"This is content"}
```

In HTML/Jade file, I have this:

```
li(ng-repeat="(number, doc) in openDocs")
   a.(data-toggle="tab", ng-href="{{'#'+number}}") {{number}}
```

AND THIS (when user clicks this row, it successfully triggers the openDoc function):

```
tr(ng-repeat="(number, doc) in otherDocs", ng-click="openDoc(number)")
```

Comment: This should not happen, so I guess something is missing. Can you reproduce it in a fiddle/plunk?

Answer (score 2):

I feel so stupid. I now have the answer thanks to trying to recreate it in jsfiddle. Here is my original code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ey9nQ/3/

My original problem was that I started with an empty object:

```
$scope.things =[];
```

This shows up fine when I output it in console.log, however doesn't work in angular. I needed to change it to:

```
$scope.things = {};
```

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/Ey9nQ/4/